# How to add event listeners to radio button - mines not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-events, event-listener

I have some inputs for dates but I only want to show them when the user clicks on a radio button "Date Range".
So my html looks like this:

```
@*@Html.RadioButton("radioTimeFilter", "range", false) Date Range*@
<input id="radioTimeFilter" type="radio" value="false"> Date Range
<div class="radio-content" style="display:none;">
    <input id="txtDateOneFilter" type="text" style="width: 70px;" placeholder="Start Date" />&nbsp;to&nbsp;
    <input id="txtDateTwoFilter" type="text" style="width: 70px;" placeholder="End Date" />
</div>
<br />
```

I would prefer to use html.radiobutton but w/e works.

Now my function to collapse looks like:

```
function addCollapsibleCapabilities(coll) {
    for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert(coll);
            this.classList.toggle("active");

            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I import the file and add the function

```
    var collapseDateRange = document.getElementById("radioTimeFilter");
    addCollapsibleCapabilities(collapseDateRange);
```

My alert is not firing.

Comment: `radioTimeFilter` is a single control, so there is no `.length` on it. Have you checked the console in your browser developer tools? It should be showing you an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting collapseDateRange to be Array which cannot be a case when you are selecting element using `document.getElementById()`. It will always give you an element object.
Just remove the forloop and set the listener directly on `coll` object.

```
function addCollapsibleCapabilities(coll) {
    coll.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert(coll);
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

If you have more than one radio element, you can use another selector as below. But provide `name` attribute to your radio element than `id`.

```
var collapseDateRange = document.getElementsByName("radioTimeFilter");
addCollapsibleCapabilities(collapseDateRange);
```

Above code will provide you NodeList array and you can use your forloop code to iterate through each radio button and set `click` event listener.

Comment: ooo thank you. Yes i switched id to getElementsByClassName and it worked